# Modifying a function without loosing sense

Tags: c, sfml

I am trying to open and close a window in csfml, my code has no error but i cannot have more than 3 branches in a conditionnal block. I am having a hard time modifying it without making errors. This is what i've done

```
int main(void)
{
    sfRenderWindow *window;
    sfVideoMode video_mode;
    sfEvent event;
    video_mode.width = 1920;
    video_mode.height = 1080;
    video_mode.bitsPerPixel = 32;

    window = sfRenderWindow_create(video_mode,"MyWindow", sfDefaultStyle, NULL);
    while (sfRenderWindow_isOpen(window)) {
        sfRenderWindow_display(window);
        while (sfRenderWindow_pollEvent(window, &event)) {
            if (event.type == sfEvtClosed)
                sfRenderWindow_close(window);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "i cannot have more than 3 branches in a conditionnal block" mean, and how does your code violate it? I see (only) three branch points in your code, all two-way.

Comment: i think azerty means 3 nested loops / if's? But ye i still dont understand the problem either. The code looks perfectly fine and logical

Comment: yes this is what i meant

Answer (score 0):

I did several projects in CSFML, and personally, I use structure in order to stock all the information.

Here is part of my code to create a window like you want:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.h>
#include <SFML/Window.h>
#include <SFML/System.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct window {
    sfVideoMode video_mode;
    sfRenderWindow *window;
} window_t;

typedef struct global {
    sfEvent event;
    window_t window;
} global_t;

void create_window(global_t *all)
{
    all->window.video_mode.height = 769;
    all->window.video_mode.width = 1280;
    all->window.video_mode.bitsPerPixel = 32;
    all->window.window = sfRenderWindow_create(all->window.video_mode, "My Hunter",
     sfClose | sfResize, NULL);
    sfRenderWindow_setFramerateLimit(all->window.window, 60);
}

void analyse_event(global_t *all)
{
    if (all->event.type == sfEvtClosed || sfKeyboard_isKeyPressed(sfKeyEscape))
        sfRenderWindow_close(all->window.window);
}

void game_loop(void)
{
    global_t all;
    create_window(&all);
    while (sfRenderWindow_isOpen(all.window.window)) {
        while (sfRenderWindow_pollEvent(all.window.window, &all.event)) {
            analyse_event(&all);
        }
        sfRenderWindow_display(all.window.window);
        sfRenderWindow_clear(all.window.window, sfBlack);
    }
}

int main()
{
    game_loop();
    return 0;
}
```

I hope it can help you.